# input/output error on NTFS drive when path is very long

Tags: ntfs

I seemed to have hit a bug in the underlying sub-system handling NTFS drives. I cannot seem to work with file paths that are more than 155 or so characters long (count includes "/mount/user/"). If the total file path is 152 characters or less everything works normally, such as `rsync`, `cp`, the file manager ...etc. However, once the character count exceeds a certain threshold then everything fails with an "input/output error"; I haven't determined the exact number but I know that 157 characters will fail.

I'm in the process of copying 4TB worth of data so manually shortening the paths isn't really an option, and I've already renamed the mount label to just 1 character but there are still files buried too deep. How do I get around this?

For reference I'm using 16.04.3 LTS, and the drive is mounted through USB, if that matters.

*note: although input/output errors are usually associated with hardware failures this is not the case; the files are perfectly fine.

Comment: This is weird. The file path limitation is 255 characters on Windows and 1024 on Linux.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto, and you can get around the 255 character limit on Winodws by using a UNC path instead of a dos drive letter path.  I just created a test ntfs volume and make a 100 character directory in it, then inside that another 100 character directory, then inside that a 200 character long file name and it worked fine on 17.04.